# PHP Redirect to another page (using Stripe)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Good day,

I am using Stripe to collect payments for my site. I have the code working to accept the payments, but I am having trouble redirecting the user to a thank you page once subscribed.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php require_once('/home4/threehs/public_html/wp-content/themes/NoFuss/config.php'); 
if ($_POST) {
    Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
    $error = '';
    $success = '';
    try {
            if (!isset($_POST['stripe_token']))
            throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
        $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
            "email"=>$_POST['stripeEmail'],
            "card" => $_POST['stripe_token'],
            "plan" => 'yearly'
));

            $success = 'HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO REDIRECT TO THANK YOU PAGE';
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }           
}

?>

HTML Signup form here
```

This is the code I am using from Stripe (and a few tutorials). It looks like on the success, I either receive a string or when I try to do a header redirect, it returns an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many different ways, but using the `Location` header is probably the most common:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com');
exit;
```

**Edit:** Forgot to note that the `exit` is intentional.  You should always include it after a redirect in order to stop processing and prevent sensitive information leaks (i.e. redirecting away from an admin page when a user doesn't have privileges).

Comment: Thanks for your response - I entered that after the success variable where I indicated in my post and received this error "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/threehs/public_html/wp-content/themes/NoFuss/brush-page.php:7) in /home4/threehs/public_html/wp-content/themes/NoFuss/brush-page.php on line 22"

Answer (score 1):

headers must come at the VERY top of the page before any data. in the middle of code won't work